# Jenkins won't deploy - SSH server 'Host key Verification failed'

Tags: jenkins, ssh, server, key, jhipster

I'm deploying an app from git to a target server with Jenkins. I've set in my project a new Jenkinsfile which its stage('deploy') is pointing at the right machine. The conection would happen through SSH.

I've been reading for the deployment to succesfully run, **both machines** (git & target server) must know each others Host keys, which are stored in known_hosts at ~/.ssh/ . Therefore I connected through ssh from the git machine to the server (prompted if I wanted to continue establishing the connection, 'yes'):

- checked the known_hosts file in git server to find the target server entry.
- checked the known_hosts file at target server to find an entry, which looks like |1|KCIHm6...lo= ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 AAAA...(bla bla).

I think it's all set for Jenkins to be able to deploy on server, but everytime I build the project from Jenkins, the moment the first ssh deploy command is ran, the deployment fails with a 'Host key Verification failed' message. I can navigate through the target server no matter if I connect through my local machine or the git server, I've tried redoing the process but I can't really replicate the first connection.

Any suggestion is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you create the ssh keys with jenkins user and restart jenkins?

Comment: No, let me try that

Comment: I'm sorry I'm not closing this thread yet. I got around the problem in a "peculiar" way but it's a temporary solution. I'll try fix it soon and let you know.

Comment: Thanks Joao, you were right. For some reason I can't select your comment as the answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create the ssh keys with jenkins user and restart jenkins.

```
su jenkins
ssh-keygen
ssh-copy-id destUser@destServer   #Type the destUSer password
```

More info [here](https://www.ssh.com/ssh/keygen/)